# Python run command and capture result - do not print result to screen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command from a python script, but I want to store the output the command produces and then check it for a substring, however it seems it is not being stored in my variable because it still prints to the screen.

So far I have this...

```
myfile = 'filename.txt'
result = subprocess.Popen(['myprogram.exe', '-f' + myfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
if result.find("error executing") != -1:
     print "error!"
else:
     print "success!"
```

I'm rather new to Python.  Can anyone shed some light on WHY when I run this script, the myprogram.exe DOES execute, but it's output is still sent to the screen.  If I print the result variable, it DOES have additional output from myprogram.exe, but I need the lines that show the error too.

Comment: Try adding `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only redirecting stdout. Looks like your program outputs errors to stderr (as expected), add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` call.